# How to create Pyspark application

Tags: apache-spark, hadoop, pyspark, hdfs

My requirement is to read the data from HDFS using pyspark, filter only required columns, remove the NULL values and then writing back the processed data to HDFS. Once the these steps are completed, we need to deleted the RAW Dirty data from HDFS. Here is my script for each operations .

Import the Libraries and dependencies

```
#Spark Version = > version 2.4.0-cdh6.3.1 

from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
sparkSession = SparkSession.builder.appName("example-pyspark-read-and-write").getOrCreate() 
import pyspark.sql.functions as F
```

Read the Data from HDFS

```
df_load_1 = sparkSession.read.csv('hdfs:///cdrs/file_path/*.csv', sep = ";")
```

Select only the required columns

```
col = [ '_c0',  '_c1',  '_c2',  '_c3',  '_c5',  '_c7',  '_c8',  '_c9', '_c10', '_C11', '_c12', '_c13', '_c22', '_C32', '_c34', '_c38', '_c40',
   '_c43', '_c46', '_c47', '_c50', '_c52', '_c53', '_c54', '_c56', '_c57', '_c59', '_c62', '_c63','_c77', '_c81','_c83'] 

df1=df_load_1.select(*[col])
```

Check for NULL values and we have any remove them

```
df_agg_1 = df1.agg(*[F.count(F.when(F.isnull(c), c)).alias(c) for c in df1.columns])

df_agg_1.show()

df1 = df1.na.drop()
```

Writing the pre-processed data to HDFS, same cluster but different directory

```
df1.write.csv("hdfs://nm/pyspark_cleaned_data/py_in_gateway.csv")
```

Deleting the original raw data from HDFS

```
def delete_path(spark , path):
    sc = spark.sparkContext
    fs = (sc._jvm.org
          .apache.hadoop
          .fs.FileSystem
          .get(sc._jsc.hadoopConfiguration())
          )
    fs.delete(sc._jvm.org.apache.hadoop.fs.Path(path), True)
```

Executing below by passing the HDFS absolute path

```
delete_path(spark , '/cdrs//cdrs/file_path/')
```

[pyspark and HDFS commands](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34012775/pyspark-and-hdfs-commands)

I am able to do all the operations successfully from `pyspark` prompt .

Now i want to develop the application and submit the job using spark-submit

**For example**

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client project.py for local 

spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster project.py for cluster
```

At this point i am stuck, i am not sure what parameter i am supposed to pass in place yarn in spark-submit. i am not sure whether simply copying and pasting all above commands and make `.py` file will help. I am very new to this technology.

Comment: Where do you want to run your code?

Comment: Since i am completely new , i am not sure whether i should i run in clinet /cluster /local mode . we have Cluster configuration [ 1 namenode , 2 data nodes ] and data is on namenode , i also need to understand which mode would be advisable for this requirement

Answer (score 0):

Basically your spark job will run on a cluster. Spark 2.4.4 supports yarn, kubernetes, mesos and spark-standalone cluster [doc](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

`--master yarn` specifies that you are submitting your spark job to a yarn cluster.

`--deploy-mode` specifies whether to deploy your driver on the worker nodes (cluster) or locally as an external client (client) (default: client)

```
spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode client project.py for client mode 

spark-submit --master yarn --deploy-mode cluster project.py for cluster mode

spark-submit --master local project.py for local mode
```

You can provide other arguments while submitting your spark job like `--driver-memory`, `--executor-memory`, `--num-executors` etc check [here](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/submitting-applications.html).

Comment: Thank you wypul but i am struggling to writing the project.py script , i need help on that , if you could help me writing the python.py script ,it would be very helpful

Comment: @Maverick just copy-paste all the steps that you have mentioned above. It will work. For eg take a look at this sample script https://github.com/apache/spark/blob/master/examples/src/main/python/pi.py